# mapping the 'n' key in vim while not searching

Tags: vim, key, mapping

Is it possible to map over the 'n' and 'N' keys without overriding the time they're used for skimming search results?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you *could* be searching for something any given time, so remapping `n` in normal mode without modifications would override the skimming.

After a little considering, if you always quit your searchings with `<C-l>` (clearing the highlights, I'm not sure if that is the default), you could indeed do something like this with a few extra helper functions:

```
/,?,*:
 --> set s:searching = true
     and do the builtin things

<C-l>:
 --> set s:searching = false
     and do the builtin things

n,N:
 --> if s:searching then use the builtin n
     else activate your own functionality
```

Comment: Why `v:searching`? You can't set this variable in latest vim (earlier ones had a bug that enabled you to add elements to `v:` dictionary). I guess you should change this to `s:searching`.

Comment: @ZyX: you are perfectly correct. Couldn't recall the prefix right away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can map a key in a certain mode. You could read over the [documentation for map](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html) for all of the available options to fine tune your mappings.

Specifically, [the map-overview](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#map-overview) for a list of the mappings and what mode they are used in.

Comment: That is true, but in relation to his question, he'd be in normal mode when searching next/previous. Overriding the n/N keys in normal mode would break search skimming, I believe.

Comment: that is true, I just figured "without overriding the time they're used" meant "without overriding normal mode"